# Behaviors for ShowFlyoutBehavior doesn't work on UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

I'm migrating my windows8.1 app to UWP and I found many of my behaviors stopped working one of them is the ShowFlyoutBehavior and the code is as following

```
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                <behaviors:ShowFlyoutBehavior />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The error message is like this Cannot add instance of type 'XX.App.Behaviors.ShowFlyoutBehavior' to a collection of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.ActionCollection'. Any idea? It works fine on Windows 8.1. I already installed Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed NuGet package

Comment: It turned out  IAction was commented out in the code which causes error.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have simple xaml:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/Logo.scale-100.png"
       Height="100" Width="100">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Awesome Flyout!" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</Image>
```

Create a custom behaviour:

```
public class OpenFlyoutAction: DependencyObject, IAction
{
    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender);

        return null;
    }
}
```

The final xaml:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/Logo.scale-100.png"
       Height="100" Width="100">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Awesome Flyout!" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <local:OpenFlyoutAction />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Image>
```

I would suggest you to read more from here https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/using-a-behavior-to-open-attached-flyouts-in-winows-81-store-apps/